# RxSwift: have a relay accept items in succession from an array

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

Let's say I have an array of Ints

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

And let's say I also have a publish Relay that accepts Int elements

```
let relay = PublishRelay<Int>()
```

Is there a better way than to for loop over my array to stuff them into the relay?

```
for num in array {
   relay.accept(num)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "better" way? "Better" could mean different things to different people.

Answer (score 2):

The `Observable.from` operator is what you are looking for:

```
Observable.from(array)
    .bind(to: relay)
```

Comment: I knew something existed, but I couldn't quite recall it. Thanks so much!